# Generate SHA, MD5 and other checksums from properties menu (added "Digests" tab)

Tags: nautilus, md5sum, checksums, file-properties

I am trying to restore a function that I had on my last box. It added a tab in the properties menu of any file called "Digests". From there I could choose any/all of the hash formats, click hash and it would generate said checksums right there.

What I am trying to find out is either the name of the package or acquire the location of it's installation.

I have started [a thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10159298#post10159298) on UbuntuForums pertaining to this already

Comment: My problem is not making or checking md5 hashes. The issue I want to resolve is, what is the package that provides this function as in the posted image. (won't let me post pics here, so I gave link to post on ubuntuforums with image.)

Comment: I don't know how gtkhash-nautilus looks like but it's supposed to add a Digests tab to file properties.

Comment: Right on. Thanks. I guess I should have looked into it further. It only seems to add the digests tab AFTER I chose multiple checksums in the preferences.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, I just installed package "gtkhash" and restarted Nautilus with "nautilus -q" and the "Digests" tab appeared on the properties page. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

There is [nautilus-gtkhash](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gtkhash) to add a context menu to nautilus.

[image: screenshot]

The standalone application is [gtkhash](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gtkhash).

[image: screenshot]

Both can be installed with

```
sudo apt install gtkhash
```

or

```
sudo apt install nautilus-gtkhash
```

After installing, restart nautilus. You can close nautilus as follows. Merely closing all the nautilus windows is not enough.

```
nautilus -q
```

After restarting nautilus, there will now be a Digest tab in the Properties dialog box.

Answer (score 7):

First, create a script to create a  message with the md5 checksum. This will also handle paths with spaces. I saved this as /usr/local/bin/md5info. Make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
zenity --info --text "$(md5sum $1 | sed 's/ /\n/')"
```

Install [nautilus-actions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nautilus-actions), with which you can add bits to the context menu.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Open System>Preferences>Nautilus Actions Configuration.

Add a new action. On the Action tab, specify
Context label: Digest
You can add a tooltip and icon if you like.

On the Command tab, under Command:
Path: md5info
Parameters: %d%f

Save the changes. You might need to kill existing nautilus windows with `nautilus -q` the first time.

Comment: I had to set the parameters as `%f` as the working directory is already `%d` and nautilus-actions seems to combine both.

Answer (score 3):

I found a better Nautilus Integrated Checksum generator. To install:

1. Download [HashTab Python Script](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/HashTab?content=122136) and extract the ".py" file to `~/.nautilus/python-extensions`
   (if the folder doesn't exist just make it)
2. Now you need to install `python-nautilus`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-nautilus
   ```
3. Last but not least we need to restart Nautilus

   ```
   nautilus -q && nautilus
   ```

Now you just select any file and go to `Properties-->Digests` and you should get this:
[image: HashTab Nautilus Python Extension]

Tested On:

- Ubuntu 11.04
- Ubuntu 12.04